# A problem occurred configuring project ':fluttertoast'

Tags: flutter, namespaces, build.gradle, android-manifest

When I add fluttertoast and run the app, I get the following error:
[error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMVLN.png)

Below is the code I just added:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lifelink_usersapp/global/global.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';


addItemToCart(String? foodItemId, BuildContext context, int itemCounter){

  List<String>? tempList = sharedPreferences!.getStringList("userCart");
  tempList!.add(foodItemId! + ":$itemCounter");

  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid).update({
    "userCart": tempList, 
  }).then((value){

    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Item Added Successfully");
    sharedPreferences!.setStringList("userCart", tempList);
  });
}
```

After removing flutter toast and commenting out the newly added code and running the app as before, the app runs without any runtime error.

- I have specified the namespace correctly.
- Also, I have not specified the package attribute in the AndroidMinifest file.

I am currently using:

- Gradle : 8.1.2
- Flutter : 3.13.6
- Java : 21
- Fluttertoast : 8.0.7

Below is app\build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"

}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    namespace "com.example.lifelink_usersapp"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
           sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
          targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.lifelink_usersapp"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1")
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics"
}
```

I try to run the code as usual and open the app. But when run, the following error message is displayed:

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':fluttertoast'.

> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
> Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

```
 If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP
```